# What word is in the middle of the Torah?

Tags: words, pentateuch-chumash

The Torah has 304,805 letters and different counts of words (such as 79,976 words). The first word is *Bereshit* and the last is *Israel*. I was just wondering (no real reason, just for curiosity): What word is in the exact middle of the Torah?

Comment: Are you also curious about the word that's 1/5 of the way through? If not, why is it less interesting than the one that's 1/2 of the way through? (Answering this can help you figure out why youre asking.)

Comment: You might like to have a look at http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1883118/jewish/What-Is-the-Midpoint-of-the-Torah.htm

Comment: @Epicentre This site doesn't actually give an answer. It mentions the middle of the large letters or something.

Comment: @sabba The Torah also has different counts of letters...

Comment: @Gabe12 - Which is why I put is as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I thought it was גחון

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 304,805 **letters**, not words. According to [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:gLqFwFcQTR4J:www.saad.org.il/elihu/emtza%2520laufer.doc%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=il), there are 79,976 words in the Torah, which means the center is between the words "אֶל יְסוֹד" ("at the base" [of the altar]) in [Vayikra 8, 15](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%97_%D7%98%D7%95).

According to [this](http://torah.125mb.com/Info.html), there are 79,977 words, and the middle one is the above-mentioned "יְסוֹד" ("base").

Comment: Do you know what versions of the Torah they are using?

Comment: @DoubleAA Unfortunately neither site states the version on which its count is based.

Comment: Shame. I'd expect bigger variance. Modern Temani Torah scrolls, for instance, have [פוטיפרע](http://www.nteiman.co.il/tort_amt/1/10.pdf) as one word. There are also traditions floating around with [פדה צור](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%96_%D7%A0%D7%93) as two

Comment: @DoubleAA Here [are](http://www.nifla-ot.co.il/articles/212.htm) a few more differences, however only "פוטיפרע" (from those mentioned) affects word-counting (as opposed to letter-counting). *Tishbi yetaretz...*

Comment: @DoubleAA is there some sort of master list floating around of all the variances in the torah and who holds by which?

Comment: @ShamanSTK Among accepted sizable modern groups? The above link by Cauthon covers the Ketiv aspects pretty well.

Comment: I just found out I messed up the numbers of the letters and the words. Should I change the whole question?

Comment: @Gabe12 I would suggest simply deleting the number, leaving only your question.

Comment: @Gabe12 While your at it, please add motivation to your question.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Masoretes, the middle word in Torah is “דָּרֹשׁ,” which is found in Leviticus 10:16. The image below comes from [Page 128 of the Codex Leningradensis](http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/pdf/264.pdf).

The Masoretic margin notes (*Masora Parva*) to the left of the column state, “חצי התורה בתיבות,” which translated from Aramaic means: “The middle of Torah by words.”

[image]

Comment: That can't be. It's hundreds of words off. The Masoretes clearly didn't mean what you think they do.

Comment: @DoubleAA - The same source (Codex Leningradensis) indicates that the middle _letter_ of Torah appears in Lev 11:42, and the middle _verse_ within Torah appears in Lev 8:8.  In other words, the Masoretes appear to have counted letters, words, and verses...

Comment: Cf. http://chabad.org/1883118 (hat-tip [Epicentre](/users/1804/epicentre) (what an appropriate name!)).

Comment: @DoubleAA The Talmud does mention that we don't "know how to properly count" which is why our calculation of the center is off... Curious as to what that means, but technically Joseph's answer is correct al pi mesora, even though Cauthon is correct according to mathematics...

Comment: According to the [summation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dsquV.png) found in the _Masorah Gedolah_ at the end of Deuteronomy, the Masoretic scholars appeared to have included and counted the “0-class” holem vowels as letters, which appear throughout the Dead Sea Scrolls as the holem _waw_ (written letter with vowel).  Thus, the numbering system of the Masoretic scholars for letter-counting appears much higher than the numbering by current systems using computers, which count only the consonant letters of the received Masoretic Text.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky That is inaccurate. The Talmud says we aren't experts in the use of matres lectionis. There is no reason to assume we'd be missing hundreds (!) of words in one half of the Torah. This answer is technically wrong in that it is misunderstanding the Masoretic note.

Comment: @DoubleAA Technically, the wording of the first half of the OP doesn't necessarily follow the second. Masoretically, his this answer is correct (and you're not offering an alternative explanation for the clearly worded note), but using the word count in the initial sentence of the OP, the other answer is. Just because you don't understand why "it's hundreds of words off" doesn't mean that it isn't what the note meant.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky "Just because you don't understand why 'it's hundreds of words off' doesn't mean that it isn't what the note meant." Actually, yes it does. They were clearly counting something besides words.

Comment: @DoubleAA provide another interpretation for teivot and I will accept that as a response. I'd propose they used a different framework for dividing letters into words (the talmud: bara-shit rather than bereishis, for example) that alters the midpoint according to our pshat. Regardless, that's still counting words, just not the words as we presently divide them.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1883118/jewish/What-Is-the-Midpoint-of-the-Torah.htm Why would בראשית be two words? You don't need to understand what they were thinking to know it wasn't words (in any sense of the word "word" as would be used in this question; we're discussing if this answers the question, not if the Masoretes were mistaken).

Comment: @DoubleAA And I'm positing that the question can be interpreted in the BOTH the Masoretic AND mathematical sense. In the former case, the first sentence is a non-sequitur. So?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky "So?" So the intention of the question is therefore crystal clear. I don't need to explain anything further apparently.